# Is it possible to get fieldset by attribute id of path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fieldset

I want to open a Step Form by attribute id of path.
Example:

```
/login.html?step=1
```

It should open the STEP 1.

By Clicking on Next Button for Step 2, the Path should Change the step=1 to step=2

I Have Uploaded  it here (DEMO): [http://jsfiddle.net/2jy3bpc7](http://jsfiddle.net/2jy3bpc7/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe implement this: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic.

I have also implented this one time in a project:

```
/*
         *   Direct links to steps
         *
         *   Only enable for development purpose
         */


        if (document.location.hash == "#step_02") {
            $('.steps').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                // fadein screen/step 02
                $('#step_02').fadeIn()
            });
        }
        if (document.location.hash == "#step_03") {
            $('.steps').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                // fadein screen/step 03
                $('#step_03').fadeIn()
            });
        }
```

Maybe it is helpfull